# how rcaller get results by runAndReturnResult

Tags: r, rcaller

How to use Rcaller to get more than one result in one time?
For example,I use

```
code.addRCode("data<-read.table(\""+ "/home/yo/Documents/Book1.csv"+ "\", header=TRUE,sep=\"\t\")");
caller.setRCode(code);
caller.runAndReturnResult("data");
```

Then,I can use `caller.getParser().getNames().size()` ...e.g.function

But if I want to run `summary(data$pH)` ,how do I should do?Add to code before?If that the "caller"belongs to which?
Thanks anyone who help me!

Answer (score 1):

you may find this here . it demostrate how we can get result from RCaller using runAndReturnValue method

http://stdioe.blogspot.com.tr/search/label/rcaller

Answer (score 1):

Use lists of results in R. For example you have a list of

```
result <- list(a=c(1,2,3), b=3.6, c=5)
```

after calling rcaller.runAndReturnResult(result), the variables a, b and c are accessible wia

```
double[] a = rcaller.getParser().getAsDoubleArray("a");
```

or

```
int c = rcaller.getParser().getAsIntegerArray("c")[0];
```

With getNames() method, you can get the names contained in the 'result' list as well.

When you use summary(), nothing changes. Suppose you make a lm() call in R like

```
ols <- lm (y ~ x + z, data=mydata)
```

and then

```
detailed <- summary(ols)
```

and this is also a list, as the returned value of lm(). You can access elements of this list using

```
double[] residuals = rcaller.getParser().getAsDoubleArray("residuals");
```

and

```
double rsquared = rcaller.getParser().getAsDoubleArray("r.squared")[0];
```

Nothing changes after summary(). Back to your code

```
code.addRCode("data<-read.table(\""+ "/home/yo/Documents/Book1.csv"+ "\", header=TRUE,sep=\"\t\")");
caller.setRCode(code);
caller.runAndReturnResult("data");
```

does not return a list, you can type rather

```
RCode code = new RCode();
code.addRCode("myresult <- list(res1=data$pH, res2=data$anotherVector)");
rcaller.setRCode(code);
caller.runAndReturnResult("myresult");
```

After all,

```
double[] pH = caller.getParser().getAsDoubleArray(pH);
```

returns your **pH** variable.

For further information, visit the official blog [here](http://stdioe.blogspot.com.tr/search/label/rcaller)